# Undocumented perks of reputation

Tags: support, reputation

Neither [Help Center > Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) nor 

[Help Center > Reputation & Moderation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)
 document that the reputation of 20000 gives you max points for the reputation component of the [The Candidate Score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252641/what-are-the-details-on-the-candidate-score-which-shows-during-an-election/252643#252643).

> 1 point for each 1000 reputation up to 20,000 reputation for a maximum of 20 points.

Are there other "things that reputation gives you" that are neither obvious nor documented in pages linked above?

Comment: 3,000 rep to nominate yourself in a moderator election (on Stack Overflow), 150 to vote in an election. Rep also gives you additional delete votes and flags [described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136020).

Comment: This isn't a perk or a privilege. The Candidate Score is just a metric used to assess candidates standing for moderator election.

Comment: A "privilege" is a site feature that gets enabled. I'd argue that campaigning for a moderator is *not* a site feature. It's just a criteria. If you go that route, then higher rep will make at least some users take your posts more seriously whether correct or not. But I wouldn't call that a "privilege".

Comment: On the other hand, it would not be out of line to document this as a brief comment below the actual privileges. Maybe something along the lines of Samuels' first comment above.

Comment: the stats @ 25k privilege is boring, nothing but site hits